# I am trying to understand part of a projection theorem proof in Hilbert spaces from some lecture notes.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

**Lemma 1.** *Let $H'$
be a closed subspace in a Hilbert space H. For any point
$x ∈ H$\H' there is unique point $y ∈ H'$ which is nearest point to x. The
vector $x − y$ is orthogonal to $H'$*
.

I understand the first part of the proof which proves existence of the minimum distance. But now I cannot understand the proof by contradiction that the vector $x-y$ is orthogonal to $H'$

Here is the snippet of the second part of the proof:

Let now $w$ be any vector from $H'$. We show that $<x-y, w> = 0$. Assume the contrary. Multiplying $w$ by the appropriate scalar, we can assume that $<x-y, w> = 0$ is real. Consider the function of a real variable $t$ given by $f(t) = d(x, y + tw)^2$. By definition, this function has a minimum at $t=0$, hence $f'(0) = 0$. On the other hand, we have
$$f(t) = (x-y-tw)^2 = d^2 + 2t<x-y,w> + t^2|w|^2$$ and $f'(0) = 0 = <x-y,w>$.

What I do not really understand is, why by *definition* the function defined above has a minimum at $t=0$?
I think that the reason is that making $t = 0$ results in $d(x,y+tw)$ giving the minimum distance, am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already proved in the existence part of the proof that there is a vector $y\in H'$ with minimal distance to $x$, i.e. $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)$ for all $z \in H'$. In particular,
$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,y+tw)$$
for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $f(0) \le f(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$  by the definition of $f$ and the claim follows.

Comment: It has become clearer now!

Comment: @Fnechz Glad to help!